# How do I make bash autocomplete use `*<search term>*` by default?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I just discovered that I can use `vim *<something>* [tab]` to autocomplete any part of a string. This is excellent for editing migrations with timestamps, etc. I was wondering. Is there is a way that I can make this the default behavior in my bash autocomplete? If so, how?

Comment: What do you mean "any part of a string"? For me, autocompletion for `vim` is pretty much just file/directory name completion.

Comment: Lets say the file name is `2138912389213_some_migration.php` with `vim *some* [tab]`, I get the filename, without having to type any part of the obnoxious timestamp. I want this to be my default behavior if possible (without having to type *).

Comment: That's not how it behaves for me, but you basically want fuzzy completion. Are you maybe looking for [this](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#fuzzy-completion-for-bash-and-zsh)?

Comment: You can also look into readline's [`menu-complete`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-menu_002dcomplete-_0028_0029) and `menu-complete-backward`: these allow you to loop through possible completions without typing anything.

Comment: Just to clarify, this isn't "for" vim. It is for bash. I just used vim as an example. It could just as easily be `cd *<long-obnoxious-directory-name>*<tab> `

Comment: Yes, I understood that. Readline's `menu-complete` and the fzf link are for general Bash behaviour, did you have a look at the links?